# Understanding the proof of Kechris' theorem 3.11

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, descriptive-set-theory

In Alexander Kechris' Classical Descriptive Set Theory, he proves a quite useful theorem (3.11) that I'm using as a vital part of a project I'm doing. However, there's a part of the proof I can't wrap my head around.

Let X be a completely metrizable space with a compatible metric d, and Y a $G_\delta$ subset of X. As such, Y can be written as $\cap_n U_n$, where the $U_n$ are open in X. Let $F_n = X\setminus U_n$, and define the metric d' on Y as such:

$d'(x,y) = d(x,y) + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}min\left\{2^{-n-1}, \left|\frac{1}{d(x,F_n)} - \frac{1}{d(y,F_n)}\right|\right\}$.

Kechris then states that it is easy to show that d' generates the same topology as d. This is not obvious to me. The inclusion one direction is obvious, since $d(x,y)\leq d'(x,y)$ for all x,y, but I'm not seeing how to prove the other direction at all.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the interpretation if $x \in F_n$ or $y \in F_n$?

Comment: @PaulFrost The metric $d'$ is being defined on $Y=\bigcap_nU_n$, so the points $x,y$ are not in any of the $F_n$'s.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I should have read more carefully ;-)

Comment: @PaulFrost And I should have written more carefully; fortunately there was still time to edit in the missing $F$.

Comment: I'd suggest first understanding the situation when $Y$ is open, i.e., when there's just one $F$ instead of countably many. Then it's an easy step to take care of finitely many $F$'s (with the given formula for $d'$, not just by taking the union and calling it a single $F$). Finally, the case of countably many $F$'s reduces to the case of finitely many thanks to the $2^{-n-1}$ in the formula; that small cutoff ensures that, when you're trying to get $d'(x,y)<\epsilon$, you can ignore all but finitely many terms in the sum, at the cost of needing $\epsilon/2$ rather than $\epsilon$.

Comment: The following is intended for visualization; I don't see that it helps with the proof. The simplest case is probably when $X=\mathbb R$ and $Y=\mathbb R=\{0\}$. With the standard metric from $X$, $Y$ is incomplete. Since we want to preserve the topology, we can't make the sequence $(1/n)$ converge, so to get completeness, we must make it non-Cauchy. One way to do that is to think in $\mathbb R^2$ and project $Y$ from the $x$-axis vertically to the graph of a  function that diverges to $\infty$ at 0, say $x\mapsto1/x$. [continued in next comment]

Comment: The first idea behind Kechris's $d'$ is to similarly push away to infinity anything in $Y$ that threatens to approach any of the $F_n$'s. The second idea is to use the factors $2^{-n-1}$ to "control" the pushing so that no single point in $Y$ gets pushed infinitely far away.

Comment: @Andreas I'm trying to understand your argument because I would like to prove the above fact by showing directly that for every $x\in Y$ and for every $B(x,R)$ $d$-ball there is a $d'$-ball contained in it. I understand your argument when the $F_n$'s are finitely many, but I don't understand why I can ignore all but finitely many of them when they are infinitely  many. Can you help me to understand your line of reasoning, please?

Comment: @LBJFS When you want the sum to be $<\varepsilon$, break the sum into two parts, namely a sum from $n=0$ to $K-1$ and a sum from $K$ to $\infty$, where $K$ is chosen so that $2^{-K}<\varepsilon/2$. Then the second of your two sums (the one from $K$ to $\infty$) is $<\varepsilon/2$, and you only need to arrange for the first sum (the one from $0$ to $K$) to also be $<\varepsilon/2$. So you only need to pay attention to the first $K$ terms of the original sum.

Comment: @Andreas First of all, I apologize for answering just now. Secondly, I think I got your argument thanks to your very plain comments. As I understand it, I can "control" the term with finitely many terms because the function $x\mapsto 1/d(x,U_n^c)$ is continuous. And finally, many thanks for the example on $\Bbb{R}$, it makes everything clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to show that if $y \in Y$ and $(x_m)$ is a sequence in $Y$ such that $d(x_m,y) \to 0$, then  $d'(x_m,y) \to 0$. So let $\varepsilon > 0$. For $m \ge m_0$ we have $d(x_m,y) < \varepsilon/2$. Choose $N$ such that $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty 2^{-n-1} < \varepsilon/4$. Hence it suffices to show that $\sum_{n=0}^N \left|\frac{1}{d(x_m,F_n)} - \frac{1}{d(y,F_n)}\right|< \varepsilon/4$ for $m \ge M$. To do so, it suffices to show that for each $n$ we have $\left|\frac{1}{d(x_m,F_n)} - \frac{1}{d(y,F_n)}\right| <  \varepsilon/4(N+1)$ for $m \ge M_n$. Then take $M = \max(M_0,\dots,M_N)$. Now observe that the distance function $d(-,F_n)$ is continuous so that $\left|\frac{1}{d(x_m,F_n)} - \frac{1}{d(y,F_n)}\right| = \left|\frac{d(y,F_n) - d(x_m,F_n)}{d(x_m,F_n)d(y,F_n)}\right| \to \frac{0}{d(y,F_n)^2} = 0$.